# current_user.role not changing upon upgrade (Stripe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

My standard current_user.role is not changing to premium within my `ChargesController` create action, even though my create (post) action follows through.  My downgrade action within my UsersController performs properly and changes a users role just find, using the same `current_user.role = 'new_role_here'` just fine.  I'm curious as to why my `current_user.role` is not changing upon a successful save message?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**ChargesController** Using stripe

```
before_action :require_sign_in

def new
    @stripe_btn_data = {
        key: Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key].to_s,
        description: "BigMoney Membership - #{current_user.email}",
        amount: 10
    }
end

def create
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: current_user.email,
      source: params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: customer.id,
      amount: @amount,
      description: "BigMoney Membership - #{current_user.email}",
      currency: 'usd'
  )

  current_user.role = 'premium'

  if current_user.save!
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for all the money, #{current_user.email}! changed to premium member, #{current_user.role}"
      redirect_to wikis_path # or wherever
  end

  # Stripe will send back CardErrors, with friendly messages
  # when something goes wrong.
  # This `rescue block` catches and displays those errors.
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:alert] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
  end
end
```

**charges/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
<% if flash[:error].present? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<label class="amount">
  <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
</label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
      data-description="A month's subscription"
      data-amount="500"
      data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'charges/create'

  get "log_in" => 'sessions#new', :as => "log_in"
  get "log_out" => 'sessions#destroy', :as => "log_out"


  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"

  get "my_account" => "users#show", :as => "my_account"

  get 'users/confirm' => 'users#confirm'

  root :to => "sessions#new"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :wikis
  resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that that if I used `current_user.update_attribute(:role, 'premium')` instead of `current_user.role = 'premium` it worked.

Comment: Make sure to accept your answer when you can.  It's the right answer, and will help others having this issue know.  Plus, you get points and a new badge for doing that.  :D

Comment: Will do.  Have to wait 48 hours ;)